# Mapping a normal coordinate system to Android screen coordinates

Tags: android, math, webview, coordinates

What I'm trying to do is map the points of a coordinate system to touch events on a specific view (second image).

Let `maxX` and `maxY` be the horizontal and vertical screen size respectively. Now I want to map something like this:
[image: Normal coordinate system]
to something like this:
[image: Android screen coordinates]

Essentially, any points in the first system would be translated to points in the second one. It seems like I'm missing something obvious here, but I just cannot wrap my head around the whole concept.

For the WebView wizards out there: I'm trying to simulate mouse clicks when the user interacts with a joystick. The output of the joystick is `angle` and `strength` which I managed to convert to coordinates using `Math.sin()` and `Math.cos()`. Using these coordinates I tried to `document.elementFromPoint(x, y).click();` with javascript, but it didn't seem to work. If you need more clarification don't hesitate to comment. Thanks in advance!

Now, if there are better ways to do this without simulating touches, let me know. My google-fu didn't find anything that worked reliably though.

Comment: If `maxX/Y` are the same for both coordinate systems, then there is a simple linear relationship between the two. Hint: write a general linear equation like `x' = ax + b` and substitute the boundary conditions to obtain the constants `a, b`.

Comment: You can obtain two pairs of simple linear simultaneous equations using the known corresponding points of both systems. E.g. X-coordinates `maxX & 0` in system 2 corresponds `1/2 maxX & -1/2 maxX` in system 1, which gives `a = 1, b = -1/2 maxX`. Do the same for `y`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured this out:

`y1 = -y + 1/2`

`x1 = x + 1/2`

`x1` and `y1` are the new coordinates in the second system.

Big thanks to @meowgoesthedog for the tip. :)